# function or parameter as template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I saw the following code:

```
template<class T, T t = T()>
class A {
    t > T()
};
```

I am confused about the second template parameter( t = T() ). Is that a function returning T or a non-type parameter? And what does it mean by comparing t and T()?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you saw? Because unless there's an obscure part of C++ I don't know about, `t > T()` is an expression that is invalid in that context.

Comment: The full code locates [here](http://www.interqiew.com/ask?ta=tqcpp02&qn=2)

Answer (score 2):

The second argument is a non-type parameter but it is not a function.

```
T t = T()
```

simply specifies a default value of the template parameter `t`.

You can create instances of the template using:

```
A<int> a1;  // Equivalent to A<int, 0>
A<int, 10> a2;

A<bool> a3;  // Equivalent to A<bool, false>
A<bool, true> a4;
```

The line

```
t > T()
```

does not make sense at all.